# Umbrello doesn't show aggregation association

Tags: umbrello

I'm trying to add an Aggregation association between two classes with Toolbar. An attribute (with *) appeares in the aggergator, but the link doesn't appear on the class diagram. If I make a Composition link, an attribute appeares, and a link with a filled diamond appeares on the diagram.

Is there any way to show Aggregation association in Umbrello?

I use it on Windows 10, Umbrello version 2.30.2 (installed from binaries)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in KDE Neon + Umbrello 2.30.3. I work around it by using composition association first and then change it into aggregation association in properties dialog ...